# How do i render css inline in ruby slim as output css is not being inserted inside a style tag

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I have the following helper function in ruby :

```
def site_css_link_tag(merchant_canonical:, site_variant:, template_previewing:)
    # TODO: will remove variant argument
    is_js_generate = merchant_canonical.nil? && site_variant.nil? && template_previewing.nil?
    url = is_js_generate ? '' : css_api_v2_shopfront_sites_url(
            merchant: merchant_canonical,
            variant: site_variant,
            template_previewing: template_previewing
          )
    # return stylesheet_link_tag url, url, media: 'all', id: 'site-css', 'data-base-url': css_api_v2_shopfront_sites_url
    cssStyles = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'public', Webpacker.manifest.lookup('shopfront_redux.css'))).html_safe
    return cssStyles
  end
```

It returns all the styles correctly , I.E. i do see the output in the browser like so:

[image: css output]

but how do i add this to a style tag ?

I have seen the ruby documentation [here](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#syntax-example). It say for javascript you can have something like :

```
javascript:
  alert('ok')
```

I tried doing the same with the css like so:

```
style: 
    site_css_link_tag(merchant_canonical: @merchant&.canonical_name, site_variant: @variant, template_previewing: @template_previewing)
```

But this variation does't seem to work ? So how do i output the css once again ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `css:`

```
css: 
  site_css_link_tag(merchant_canonical: @merchant&.canonical_name, site_variant: @variant, template_previewing: @template_previewing)
```